# How to track the total SOL rewards? I see 4 reward types, but I'm not sure which to use

Tags: validator, staking, rewards, vote-account

I see 4 reward types, but I'm not sure which to use. I'd like to track total rewards paid out.

- Fee,
- Rent,
- Staking,
- Voting,

To my understanding:

- Fee -> Is this related to transaction fees, if so why is this under rewards?
- Rent -> This must be the rent payments
- Staking -> SOL paid to stakers?
- Voting -> SOL paid to voters?

This would mean that to track total SOL token rewards I should track Staking + Voting. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your definition of rewards, which is why there are 4 types. Transaction fees are also considered "block rewards" to the validator that produced the block, same as rent.

If you only want to track inflation rewards, then yes, you'll only care about staking and voting rewards.

To give you a little more guidance, if you're getting these with `getBlock`https://docs.solana.com/developing/clients/jsonrpc-api#getblock, they'll only be available on the first block of an epoch.

For example, here's the first block of epoch 382 on mainnet: https://explorer.solana.com/block/165024004/rewards, with voting / staking rewards. The previous and following blocks will *not* have those rewards.